# Where were these characters during the Battle of Wakanda in Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Although it isn't clear whether **W'Kabi** and **Nakia** were

> "*dusted*" or not by the snap,

is there any information regarding their whereabouts when Proxima Midnight and Cull Obsidian led the Outriders' attack on Wakanda?

Comment: See my update below, we have confirmation on Nakia but nothing for W'Kabi yet that I can find.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although the information on W'Kabi isn't revealed just yet Nate Moore has gone on record saying Marvel does know where they are and we do know where Nakia was.

> We definitely know where Nakia is and we know where W'Kabi is, and that was stuff we talked about with the Russo brothers and with Markus and McFeely. So I think as you move forward through the Marvel Cinematic Universe those stories will be told, if not right away pretty soon.
>
> <sub>[Cinema Blend, Where Was Nakia During Avengers: Infinity War? Here’s What Marvel Says](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2420712/where-was-nakia-during-avengers-infinity-war-heres-what-marvel-says)</sub>

He has also said it will likely be revealed in *Avengers: Endgame* so that is probably why they haven't commented on it yet. Having watched the film now though I can say that this wasn't the case and *Endgame* did not give us any further details. However, in Phase 4 I believe there is going to be a *Black Panther* sequel so we should find out there.

> I don't want to spoil it, but Avengers 4 obviously will deal with the fallout of Avengers 3 and I think you may get some hints there.
>
> <sub>[Cinema Blend, Where Was Nakia During Avengers: Infinity War? Here’s What Marvel Says](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2420712/where-was-nakia-during-avengers-infinity-war-heres-what-marvel-says)</sub>

Joe Russo has commented that Nakia was on missions "deep undercover" during *Avengers: Infinity War*.

> When asked why she didn’t appear in “Infinity War,” Joe said, “She’s on missions.” Anthony added, “Yeah, deep undercover.”
>
> <sub>[HuffPost, 'Avengers: Infinity War' Directors Reveal Who Died And Survived Off Screen](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/avengers-infinity-war-directors-confirm-which-characters-died-off-screen_n_5af5f6fee4b032b10bfaa3a0)</sub>

It is highly possible that she was at the first Wakandan International Research Center or running missions for it as she was appointed to oversee the social outreach by T'Challa.

> **T'Challa:** And that building, and that one over ther.... This will be the first Wakandan International Research Center.
>
> *Shuri smiles at the surprise.*
>
> **T'Challa:** Nakia will oversee the social outreach... And you will spearhead the science and information exchange.
>
> <sub>[*Black Panther*](https://waltdisneystudiosawards.com/media/scripts/black-panther/)</sub>

W'Kabi was likely in prison considering he had "betrayed" T'Challa and therefore Wakanda and had surrendered to Okoye which ended the battle.

Answer (score 4):

*Black Panther: Wakanda Forever* reveals what happened to those two characters after the events of *Black Panther* (before *Avengers: Infinity War*).

W'Kabi was imprisoned for treason after siding with Killmonger in *Black Panther*.

> **M'Kathu** (*referring to Okoye, W'Kabi's wife*)**:**  She raised a spear against her own husband for Wakanda.
> **Queen Ramonda:** Where is her treacherous husband now? But in a place where she can visit if she wished. [...]

In *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever*, it was revealed that Wakanda has established outreach centers in various countries, the results of T'Challa's initiative back in *Black Panther*. Nakia is revealed to be in the Wakandan outreach center in Haiti. Queen Ramonda states that Nakia left Wakanda after the events of *Black Panther* (six years prior to *Wakanda Forever*):

> **Queen Ramonda** (*to Nakia*)**:** It's been six years since you left us.